# Is installation of MS VS 2013 Ultimate and WDK 8.1 Update is quite enough for kernel-mode driver development?

Tags: windows, driver, development-environment

I need to develop a kernel-mode driver. I already have MS VS 2013 Ultimate installed on my computer with Windows 7 OS. Is installation of WDK 8.1 Update on my computer further to MS VS 2013 Ultimate is quite enough for kernel-mode driver development? And how can I check accuracy of WDK 8.1 Update installation after it has been installed on my computer? I would be very much obliged to you for any help.

Comment: I have vs 2013 ultimate and I installed wdk8.1. but the driver menu not appear in visual c++ menu. why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is enough to build, deploy and debug your kernel mode drivers. Just install VS 2013 and then WDK 8.1. Once that is done, you should see a "Driver" menu in the Visual Studio toolbar, and the various driver project templates should become available through Visual Studio.